python bitcoin-explorer library cant initialize BitcoinDB
I am trying to use bitcoin-explorer python library. I have the path pointing to where bitcoin core stores its data. When I initialize the BitcoinDB object I get this error
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'block hash not found in block index!', C:\Users\runneradmin\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\bitcoin-explorer-1.2.20\src\parser\block_index.rs:125:18
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\turfa\Desktop\block_mind\store.py", line 20, in <module>
    bexdb = bex.BitcoinDB("D:/bits")
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\turfa\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\bitcoin_explorer\__init__.py", line 
82, in __init__
    self.db = _BitcoinDB(str(path), tx_index)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pyo3_runtime.PanicException: block hash not found in block index

Does anyone know why I would see this error?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
